# Receiving the coordinates of a mouse drag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent

I want to get coordinates of a mouse drag.
I have canvas and inside him I draw same object after I want to get the coordinates of the new mouse (pixel) grab the object,
my code is in javascript.
my object not in tag elemnts of html just drawing inside the canvas with pixel and I want to grab him with mouse and need the new coordination of the mouse.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas is a kind of 2d image element/tag, so there is no direct way to drag the objects inside canvas.

You need to listen for mouse events inside the canvas, and repaint the canvas based on these events.
Listen these 3 events for dragging the objects inside canvas

```
function handleMouseDown(e) {
    var mousePos = getMousePosition(canvas, e);
    // if current position matches the object postion
    // set a flag and monitor mouse move and mouse up event  
}
function handleMouseUp(e) {
    var mousePos = getMousePosition(canvas, e);
    //if your flag is true, then move the object to here and reset flag
}
function handleMouseMove(e) {
    var mousePos = getMousePosition(canvas, e);
    //Handle if you need smooth drag experience
}
function getMousePosition(canvas, e) {
   var boundary = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    // (e.clientX, e.clientY)  => Mouse coordinates wrt whole browser
    //  (boundary.left, boundary.top) => Canvas starting coordinate
    return {
      x: e.clientX - boundary.left,  
      y: e.clientY - boundary.top
    };
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp, false);
```

Comment: thanks for the comment but I try this and I get in console NAN when I print this value e.clientX - boundary.left,  
       e.clientY - boundary.top